# GAE blobstore is killing me

Tags: image, google-app-engine, blob

I followed this tutorial :
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/usingimages

And it's killing me...I managed to make it work...however I was not able to make it suite my needs...problem is that i want to serialize my Model using json...

1. Why do they put the avatar = db.BlobProperty() in the model and not use a reference to that blob ?...Is there any reason whatsoever?
2. I could not find a decent tutorial, on how to store an image in Blob, and then store its location/ key/reference in a Model..Any suggestions?
   With the code from below...i am doing exacty what is in the tutorial...how do I get the reference to that pic , and how do I store it???

   ```
   pic = self.request.get('img')
   pic = db.Blob(pic)
   ```

What i managed to do is to store the id of the entity in JSON, and use that id to retrieve and display the pic. And i display the pic with the following code:

```
class Image(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def get(self):
    #product = db.get(self.request.get('img_id'))

    product = MenuProduct.by_id(int(self.request.get('img_id')))
    if product.small_pic:
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'image/png'
        self.response.out.write(product.small_pic)
    else:
        self.error(404)
```

1. I am guessing that all efficiency goes to hell by using this approach ...Right?

Sorry is my post sounds messy...but I am kind of tired of the "great" poor documentation related to this topic.

Comment: Try this: http://upload.gae-init.appspot.com/resource/upload/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than store the blob as a BlobProperty, you should use the separate [Blobstore](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview) service and store the [BlobKey](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/blobkeyclass) in the model.

Comment: That is all explained in the links.

Comment: Thanks..i did this part..but now i face another challenge...Maybe you can help with that too : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15997213/processing-image-from-the-blob-gae